# How can I update a file without downloading it again

Tags: windows-7, download

I have a file that I want to update whenever required, not scheduled, but I don't want to download the large file (approx. 110 MB) over and over again.

Is there any way to fill in the missing data to the local copy without downloading the original again and again. I do not control the server and only have access to it via http.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: It would be helpful to edit your question to include the information you put in your comment to user2972191 indicating that the file resides on a web server and that you only have http based access to the file.

Answer (score 1):

Tried using `rsync`?

> It is famous for its delta-transfer algorithm, which reduces the amount
>          of data sent over the network by sending only the differences between the source
>          files and the existing files in the destination.

If you were using linux, it would probably be ready to go now. A [duckduckgo web search for rsync for windows](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=rsync+for+windows) found these potentially useful links:

- [DeltaCopy](http://www.aboutmyip.com/AboutMyXApp/DeltaCopy.jsp)

  > In general terms, DeltaCopy is an open source, fast incremental backup program. Let's say you have to backup one file that is 500 MB every night. A normal file copy would copy the entire file even if a few bytes have changed. DeltaCopy, on the other hand, would only copy the part of file that has actually been modified. This reduces the data transfer to just a small fraction of 500 MB saving time and network bandwidth.
- [Rsync for Windows on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/528298/rsync-for-windows)
- [The rsync Tool In Windows](http://www.rsync.net/resources/howto/windows_rsync.html)

Answer (score 0):

Sanoo, if you have absolute control of this file and you want to update this file yourself whenever you want, but you do not want to download it yourself, you could automate the process using a batch script, combination of ftp and cron (linux) or Task Schudeler (on Windows).

It would update the file automatically for you and you do not have to download the file yourself.

You could configure when this file would be downloaded/updated (repetitively or not) automatically or you just have to call the script or double click on it whenever you want, and the script (or batch file) would do the job for you.

I hope I could help.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply and interest but I do not want to schedule when to download the file but to update it without downloading the whose file again. No, I do not control the download server, the file is over an http or https connection, whichever works.

Comment: Only patch files can update your existing file without downloading a complete version of a file. Normally, patch files are much smaller than the original file. The file owner could use patch files maker software to release the patch files.